# Why am I unable to import SVG in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jestjs, enzyme

This is the component I want to test

footer/index.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import logoImg from "@/assets/images/components/header/logo-header.svg";
import HeaderTextImg from "@/assets/images/components/header/header-text.svg";

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div>Footer</div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

When I run the test by `npm run test`, it shows error
[image]
[image]

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage", 
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
```

**What I tried**

I tried to use `jest-svg-transformer` in `package.json` like below:

```
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
            "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
        }
```

it shows error too:

```
    ● Invalid transformer module:
      "/Users/CCCC/Desktop/SourceTree/my-proj/node_modules/jest-svg-transformer/lib/index.js" specified in the "transform" object of Jest configuration
      must export a `process` or `processAsync` or `createTransformer` function.
      Code Transformation Documentation:
      https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
```

**Update 1**

I also tried

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer",
}
```

but not working too

**Update 2**

Tried [svg-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-jest) too but still not working

Answer (score 2):

- Install camelcase package (npm install -D camelcase) (yarn add -D camelcase)
- Create fileTransform.js file in your jest directory

/jest/transforms/fileTransform.js

```
const path = require('path');
const camelcase = require('camelcase');

module.exports = {
    process(src, filename) {
        const assetFilename = JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename));
    if (filename.match(/\.svg$/)) {
        // Based on how SVGR generates a component name:
        // https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr/blob/01b194cf967347d43d4cbe6b434404731b87cf27/packages/core/src/state.js#L6
        const pascalCaseFilename = camelcase(path.parse(filename).name, {
            pascalCase: true,
        });
        const componentName = `Svg${pascalCaseFilename}`;
        return `const React = require('react');
  module.exports = {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ${assetFilename},
    ReactComponent: React.forwardRef(function ${componentName}(props, ref) {
      return {
        $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
        type: 'svg',
        ref: ref,
        key: null,
        props: Object.assign({}, props, {
          children: ${assetFilename}
        })
      };
    }),
  };`;
    }

    return `module.exports = ${assetFilename};`;
},
};
```

- Add the following in package.json:

  ```
  transform: {
         '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '<rootDir>/jest/transforms/fileTransform.js',
  },
  ```

Comment: is svg working?

Comment: @CCCC Have a look at this working webpack react boilerplate setup:
(https://github.com/react-custom-projects/webpack-react-boilerplate)

Comment: doesn't seem to work with create react app

Comment: https://github.com/react-custom-projects/webpack-react-boilerplate/blob/master/jest/jest.config.js best to use this